# How do I secure a zone with dlv.isc.org's DLV service?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

I'm setting up domain-lookaside validation. I think I got mostly everything correct. I followed the directions here: https://dlv.isc.org/about/using. I registered my domain and uploaded the key signing key, signed my zone with `-l dlv.isc.org` option, added dlv.isc.org as a foreign name server for my domain in the zone files. named fails silently. I even changed `/dev/null` to `/var/log/named.log` to squeeze some info out of named. I checked the changes were made but it didn't work I don't know what to check or try.

**I'm asking 2 questions:**

1. Strategies to glean info from named when it fails silently like its doing
2. Is the configuration correct. My limited understanding of DNS and DNSSEC tell me this should work

forward file:

```
$TTL 3600;

@ IN SOA ns1.sub.db.archives.net. dlv.isc.org. (
2014112100  ; serial
4h      ; refresh
1h      ; retry
7d      ; expiration
1h      ; minimum
)
$INCLUDE Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+07374.key
$INCLUDE Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+24586.key

        IN  NS  ns1.sub.db.archives.net.
        IN  NS  ns1.db.archives.net.
        IN  NS  dlv.isc.org.

dlv.isc.org.    IN  A   149.20.1.5
ns1.db.archives.net.    IN  A   10.103.35.66
ns1     IN  A   10.103.35.64
luke        IN  A   10.103.35.64
bo      IN  A   10.103.35.65
daisy       IN  A   10.103.35.66
sheriff     IN  A   10.103.35.67
boss        IN  A   10.103.35.68
dlv.sub.db.archives.net. 0 IN TXT "DLV:1:blablabla"

dlv.isc.org. IN DNSKEY 257 3 5 BEAAAAPHMu ...TDN0YUuWrBNh
```

reverse file:

```
$TTL 3600

@ IN SOA ns1.sub.db.archives.net. dlv.isc.org. (
2014112100  ; serial #
4h              ; refresh
1h              ; retry
7d              ; expiration
1h              ; minimum
)

                IN      NS  ns1.sub.db.archives.net.
                IN      NS  ns1.db.archives.net.
        IN  NS  dlv.isc.org.

5.1.20.149  IN  PTR dlv.isc.org.
66.35.103.10    IN  PTR ns1.db.archives.net.
64  IN  PTR ns1.sub.db.archives.net.
64  IN  PTR luke.sub.db.archives.net.
65  IN  PTR bo.sub.db.archives.net.
66  IN  PTR daisy.sub.db.archives.net.
67  IN  PTR sheriff.sub.db.archives.net.
68  IN  PTR boss.sub.db.archives.net.
```

dnssec-signzone command:

```
dnssec-signzone -l dlv.isc.org -o sub.db.archives.net -k Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+24586.key sub.db.archives.net.fwd Ksub.db.archives.net.+008+07374.key
```

named:

```
[root@test master]# service named start
Starting named:                                            [FAILED]
```

Comment: Downvoters how can I improve the question?

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters, but I would expect it to be because there are multiple `file not found` errors in your log output. Those errors are self-explanatory and they have not been addressed.

Comment: ah. sorry. I forgot to mention the files in question exist and I can confirm this

Comment: They don't, trust me. Or at least not in the directory that you think they do. All file paths are relative to the `directory` statement in your `options {};` block. If applicable, make sure you're considering the chroot as well. These files are *definitely* not being found.

Comment: I thought about what you said. I always use absolute paths in conf files if that may be what, you're referring to, I also thought it may have been the keys, so I started over, remade the keys, re-signed the forward file, fixed up minor errors but now named fails silently. I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: I hope its ok but I re-wrote the question to show the new info

Comment: @jasondancks The main problem I have with the edit is that there's no longer any clear question.

Comment: Please note that ISC DLV's service has been shut down since early October '17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Strategies for seeing why `named` fails to start:

   - Check `named-checkconf -zj` output. (`named-checkconf` as well as `named-checkzone` should probably be part of your regular workflow, not only for troubleshooting)
   - Check the logs. (`named` logs to syslog by default, see your `named.conf` for any logging configuration you have have that may override this)
   - If none of the above helps (unlikely), there is also the option to check which parameters you normally have in your `named` command line and start it manually with `-g` added to your normal set of parameters (this forces `named` to stay in the foreground and log to stderr).

2. There are numerous obvious problems with the zone data included in the question that are not in any way specific to DNSSEC or DLV. To be quite frank, I would recommend that you read up on DNS fundamentals  as a first step.
   Some problems that I spotted were the following, please consult the logs and/or `named-check{conf,zone}}` output as well.

   - The `SOA` records have very unlikely RNAME values (`dlv@isc.org`)
   - `dlv.isc.org` is listed as a nameserver but I very much doubt it hosts your zones.
   - `dlv.isc.org.  IN  A  ...` doesn't look like it belongs in this zone.
   - `ns1.db.archives.net.  IN  A  ...` doesn't look like it belongs in this zone.
   - `dlv.isc.org.  IN  DNSKEY  ...` doesn't look like it belongs in this zone.
   - `5.1.20.149  IN  PTR dlv.isc.org.` -  Ignoring that it's written incorrectly, this is yet another record that doesn't belong.
   - `66.35.103.10  IN  PTR ns1.db.archives.net.` probably belongs but is written incorrectly.

(My impression from the question is that the two zones are `sub.db.archives.net` and `35.103.10.in-addr.arpa`, which is what I've based the out-of-zone statements on. Seeing the actual configuration in addition to the zone data would confirm this.)

Comment: Thanks so much. Something strange is definitely going on. `named-checkzone` didn't like the out-of-zone data but said the zone was valid. `/usr/sbin/named` actually ran and loaded the conf and zone files (again warning about the out of zone data). So its the init.d script thats failing technically a correctly defined zone.

Answer (score 2):

The actual `file not found` errors come across as fairly self-explanatory (no such files exist, I suppose?).

However, `DS` records live in the parent zone, alternatively `DLV` records live at the DLV server.

This means that  your step 4 does not exist (as per the guide you linked).

Can you really not get the DS records into the parent zone instead?  DLV was mostly a stopgap measure early on and should not be the first choice.

Also see [In-line signing (and auto-dnssec maintain)](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00711/0/In-line-Signing-With-NSEC3-in-BIND-9.9-A-Walk-through.html), that is generally a better option for zone signing and key management compared to calling dnssec-signzone manually.

Comment: As far as DLV is concerned its my only real choice